# Arrays not merging in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

I've made a C-Program to, input values in two separate one-dimensional arrays and then merge them in a single one-dimensional array, where the merging takes place in a separate function **(Function with argument and no return value)**, but the result is displaying the first array values again(two times).

Please assist.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main();
void merger(int [],int , int [], int , int []);

void main()
{
    int x,X[x],y,Y[y],z,Z[z],i;

    printf("Please enter the size of FIRST array: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Please enter the size of SECOND array: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    printf("\nPlease enter the values for the FIRST array: \n");
    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
        scanf("%d",&X[i]);

    printf("\nPlease enter the values for the SECOND array: \n");
    for(i=0; i<y; i++)
        scanf("%d",&Y[i]);

    merger(X,x,Y,y,Z);
    getch();
}

void merger(int A[],int size1, int B[], int size2, int C[])
{
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<size1; k++)
        C[k]=A[k];

    for(k=0 ; k<size2; k++)
        C[k+size1]=B[k];

    printf("\n\n The MERGED ARRAY is: \n C[] = {");
    for(k=0; k<(size1+size2); k++)
        printf(" %d,",C[k]);
    printf("\b }");
}
```

Comment: Your declarations for X, Y, and Z are not correct. Think about what values x, y, and z have at the moment X, Y, and Z are declared.

Comment: Side note: Whoever teaches you `void main()` and `#include <conio.h>` is teaching stuff from the 1990s. These two snippets are not used in modern C.

Comment: @JeffHolt thanks for pointing that, I earlier thought it was correct as the user was assigning a value to 'x'  and 'y',  but writing **int x, X[x]** is not correct.

Comment: @RolandIllig, today I got to know that the standard prototype for **main()** is **int main(void)** and not *void main()*, thank you for your help.

Comment: @4386427 I'll study about it.

Comment: I got tired of seeing this surprisingly common FAQ so I now wrote a self-answered Q&A about how to use VLA, here: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

Comment: @Lundin, Informative article!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code produces a series of invalid reads and writes. The problem starts here:

```
int x,X[x],y,Y[y],z,Z[z],i;
```

The variable `x` is not initialized and thus has an indeterminate value. This indeterminate value is used for the length of the variable length array `X`. The same holds for `Y` and `Z`.

To solve this, first obtain values for the dimensions, and allocate memory for these arrays afterwards. Preferably using dynamic memory allocation instead of using variable length arrays, but that's another discussion.

Some additional problems:

- `void main()` is not a valid signature for the main function. Instead, use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.
- Using the `conio` header and `getch()` is unnecessarily limiting the platforms your code will run on. Using only `stdio.h` accomplishes the same while being portable. The `getch()` function can be omitted here.

Comment: *Using stdio.h and getchar() accomplishes the same while being portable*, no `getch()` is not buffered therefore there is no need for a newline character to continue.

Comment: @alex01011 Good catch! Thank you. For the purpose of the program, neither `getch()` nor `getchar()`is needed, at least. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Yun thanks for your answer, I got plenty of doubts cleared today; the code is working now.

Comment: @alex01011, yes you are right, I was only using **getch()** as a tool to pause the screen at the end of the program so the display output is viewable. But ultimately it's a poor logic implementation.